# Skype URI's in Java for Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, skype

I'm currently trying to make use of the Skype URI API, which basically should be able to open skype and instantiate a chat-conversation (which I'll fix when I make this work). I've been googling for a while now and I've also been going through the Skype URI docs, but I still haven't found the solution. I've tried to things that came up when I googled, but none of them worked. Both

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] { "open" , "-a", "skype:" }) ;
```

and

```
try 
{ 
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", "skype:"}); 
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{ }
```

didn't work, and I don't know why, so that is my question. I'm on a Mac, so it should be able to function on a Mac. Honestly, I'm 99% sure that the second one is for Windows, so it's clear why that didn't work. But how do I make this work?

This is where I got the `skype:` from: http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference#uriSwitchFocusToSkype

On the docs they do not have any examples how to do this for mac.